# SHParseDisplayName fails with ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when passed existing directory whose name ends with a space character

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm developing a file manager application, and noticed that some functions don't work with an existing folder that ends with a space symbol. E. g. "E:\1 \". This isn't specific to this particular folder, but indeed to any one with a space as the last character of the folder's name. For such folders, `SHParseDisplayName` returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

I'm calling `SHParseDisplayName` like so from C++:

```
ITEMIDLIST* idPtr = nullptr;
const auto result = SHParseDisplayName(L"E:\\1 \\", nullptr, &idPtr, 0, nullptr);
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shparsedisplayname) doesn't specify any edge cases, nor any ways in which the input path should be pre-processed. Regardless, I tried decorating it with quotes:

```
SHParseDisplayName(L"\"E:\\1 \\\"", nullptr, &idPtr, 0, nullptr);
```

And supplying a UNC path:

```
SHParseDisplayName(L"\\\\?\\E:\\1 \\", nullptr, &idPtr, 0, nullptr);
```

Both of which results in `E_INVALIDARG`.

Of note: `SHParseDisplayName` does work properly for items nested inside such a folder, e. g. `L"E:\\1 \\some_internal_folder\\"`, just not the folder whose name ends with a space itself.

Is there any workaround? Windows Explorer seems to work just fine with such folders (as one would expect).

Also, `SHParseDisplayName` isn't the only Windows API function that fails for such folders. Another example of the same behavior is `ILCreateFromPathW`.

Comment: Are you sure about Explorer? If I try to rename a folder to put a space on the end it ignores it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: That I didn't try. I created the folder with my file manager, and Explorer is able to show a tooltip for it, a context menu, recycle the folder etc. These actions don't work in my manager for this particular folder.

Comment: Explorer won't let you create a folder with a space on the end which suggests neither should your app.

Comment: problem in conversion from win32 dos path no nt path. if path end with space - it dropped. as result wrong name- file not found. but if you set \ at the end - after space - it correct converted in this case

Comment: Hm. Explorer is unable to move this folder, nor show its creation / modification date...

Comment: test with `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U_WithStatus` convertation - in case *"\\\\?\\c:\\a "* and *"c:\\a \\"* space will be at end, in case *"c:\\a "* -space will be removed. however in what is question ?

Comment: i check - explorer fail handle files with space at the end but far manager - do this ok

Comment: and this not only for directory related but for any file. for not folder you can not append \ to end. use " no sense because this used only when we have command line which need **parse** and separate file path from rest. so use \\?\ prefix as solution

Comment: @RbMm: as I mentioned in the question, I tried \\?\ and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - \\?\ solve problem if you will be use such path in `CreateFileW` api. the shell functions - can not understand  \\?\ at all. so here also question - you need exactly SH function ? here possible no solution at all. or CreateFileW/NtOpenFile/NtCreateFile is ok ?

Comment: @RbMm: Thank you for clarifying that. Unfortunately, I don't see a way around `SH...` functions when trying to display the system shell context menu for this item. The question is: why does the context menu for such a folder work in Explorer?

Comment: *Windows Explorer seems to work just fine with such folders* - i be not say. partially work only. even enter to folder only after **second** double click on it. can not rename/delete, etc. problems in win32 <-> nt path conversion. such conversion remove space in the end. \\?\ work here only because it replaced to \??\ and other paths not parsed with this prefix. the SH functions + additional layer of problems - it not support \\?\ at all. as result we always will be have problem in win32 api with such paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File and Folder names that begin or end with the ASCII Space (0x20)
>   will be saved without these characters. File and Folder names that end
>   with the ASCII Period (0x2E) character will also be saved without this
>   character. All other trailing or leading whitespace characters are
>   retained.
>
> The Win32 API (CreateFile, FindFirstFile, etc.) uses a direct method
>   to enumerate the files and folders on a local or remote file system.
>   All files and folders are discoverable regardless of the inclusion or
>   location of whitespace characters.

Refer to "[Support for Whitespace characters in File and Folder names](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2829981/support-for-whitespace-characters-in-file-and-folder-names-for-windows)"

And blog "[MS-DOS also allowed spaces in file names, although vanishingly few programs knew how to access them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090709-00/?p=17563).

So for existing files/folders with space at the end of names, either use Win32 API (CreateFile, FindFirstFile, etc.) or replace them with a new name without trailing or leading whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks! Curiously, I have much fewer problems (if any at all) with folders beginning with a space; only those that end with a space.